# Is it possible to write a VBA code that removes duplicates from only cells that are highlighted?

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to only remove duplicates of cells that are highlighted (in yellow). I was wondering if it is possible to do that.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a question about general capabilities, not specific programming problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say we have a column of values, some of which are hi-lighted in yellow.  Say the column contains duplicates.  For example:

[image]

This macro will examine the yellow cells and remove duplicates:

```
Sub TheKingInYellow()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, wf As WorksheetFunction
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    For i = N To 2 Step -1
        With Cells(i, 1)
            v = .Value
            c = .Interior.ColorIndex
            If wf.CountIf(Range(Cells(i - 1, 1), Cells(1, 1)), v) > 0 And c = 6 Then
                .Delete
            End If
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Here is the result:

[image: xx]

Comment: Note that this will deleted highlighted cells if the value exists elsewhere highlighted or not (as apposed to deleting among the highlighted cells only).  Granted, OP is unclear on if this is the required behaviour.

Comment: @chrisneilsen...ouch! ........you are correct!

Comment: @Gary'sStudent what would I have to add if I want the entire row deleted? besides that specific cell. Sorry i'm fairly new to VBA so I have no idea

Comment: nevermind, figured it out. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't specify what range you want to effect, I wrote this so you have to select the data first and then run the code.

It loops through each cell in the selection and checks the background color.  While there are many shades of yellow, Interior.ColorIndex = 6 is the common preset most people go with.  Any rows with that glorious "highlighter" yellow get deleted :)

```
Sub NoYellow()
    Dim r As Range

For Each r In Selection
    If r.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then r.EntireRow.Delete
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Not really sure why someone would downvote this (perhaps out of spite, as it's generally frowned upon here to provide answers for ppl who do not demonstrate a minimum amount of effort towards solving the problem on their own), but I will confirm that this method does work to delete highlighted rows.

Comment: @david neither personal accusations nor explanations of downvotes are required on SO.  That said, downvoted because this answer does not address the question ie deletion of _duplicates_

Comment: @chrisneilsen yes you're right about both. I do think that an explanation accompanying a downvote gives the asker (or answerer, in this case) the opportunity to improve. Without an explanation, it is not always clear. as for the satisfaction of this answer, you're also correct but I don't think it's a stretch to assume that the items desired to be deleted are *already* highlighted -- in which case the question is really "how do I delete highlighted items"... Of course the Q could use some clarification from OP -- which is why the Q has so many downvotes itself :)

Comment: Aye, I read it as his duplicates were the ones in yellow.  Lesson learned - I'll ask for clarification if there's even a smattering of assumption needed on my part.